# Convert object of Line into bitmap as well as in Byte array In windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I got stuck at the point of conversion I want to draw a Line using canvas now I want to save this line in bitmap data for future use How it can possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [`WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638675%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), using your Canvas as a parameter for the constructor. Then use the [`SaveJpeg`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method to save the picture.

Comment: WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(line, null); I have to save particular line not Whole canvas have you any other idea Can I store line as an xml for further use or any other way we can access comment will be appreciated.

Comment: Actually I have to draw lines and suppose we close app and use another app when move to drawing app we can able to undo and redo drawing that's why I think I store line as byte bitmap data have you any other idea?

Comment: Then it isn't bitmap data ;) You can easily make your own XML-based format to save the lines. Basically, all you have to store is the line's coordinates and the color. From there, you can redraw the line when loading the XML file.

Comment: One more thing can we create XML at runtime and save for further use?

Comment: Of course. You can use the `XDocument` class to read or store the XML file in the isolated storage (the phone's storage reserved to your app)

Comment: Hi KooKiz I was trying to implement XML for drawing but not succeed,I want to store  MyStroke.StylusPoints.Add(e.StylusDevice.GetStylusPoints(drawCanvas));

Comment: Hello I am facing problem suppose I add one elemt while user end drawing but after some while user starts again the new line is drawn so how can I store more than one line info color,co-ordinate?